# Clipping/exporting multiple selected vector layers in map to extent of another raster/vector layer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, export, spatial-database

Is there a way to clip/export selected vector layers (more than one) in a map to the extent of another raster/vector layer at a time?? in Arcgis or any other software.

I am using Arcgis10. I am having many vector layers as shown in figure. I want to clip for example "Australia" region of all vector layers. I can do it each and every layer separately. But I want to clip all layers/few layers in the map to Australia region at a time as a bundle. So-that I can avoid re-work of clipping each layer and save time.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [Batch Processing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_batch_processing/00210000000w000000/) is the simplest way to go.

1. Locate the **Clip** tool in the **ArcToolbox** window (**Analysis Tools** toolbox, **Extract** toolset) where you can right-click on it and choose **Batch**. (Note: You could do this from the Search window at 10.1 but not 10.0.)
2. Multiple select your layers and drag them in as **Input Features**
3. Select the polygon layer you want to clip with and drag that into the top cell of the **Clip Features**, then right flick and choose Fill to copy to the rest of that column
4. Hit the **Environments** button and set **Current Workspace** to the geodatabase or folder you want to output your feature classes into - this should populate the **Output Feature Class** with names based on each input feature class
5. Hit **OK** to run

Answer (score 1):

```
   import arcpy
        import string
        output=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)   #output gdb file path

        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True;

        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "layers")[0]
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
            if lyr.visible == True:
                print lyr;
                #arcpy.AddMessage(lyr);
                desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)

                path = desc.path
                layersource=str(path)+"\\"+desc.name
                layersource2=output+"\\"+desc.name
                #arcpy.AddMessage(layersource2);
                #arcpy.AddMessage(output)
                arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True;
                #arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr,output,)
                if (layersource2[:-4]=='.shp'):

                    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr,layersource2[:-4])
                else:
                    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr,layersource2)
                #arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management()
        #mxd.save()
        #del mxd
```

This script can export current features in arcmap to a gdb file path you can use this to clip features at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If all your data is stored in one geodatabase it is possible to use the tool [Copying a geodatabase using Extract Data Wizard in ArcMap](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000030000000) here you can select which data layers you want to export.